# Apache Camel: prevent trimming the space character after passing the property to the bean

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to search for a regex in the text and seperate the substrings by the delimiter ", ". Currently I am facing the problem that the second delimiter character " " space
is being trimed after passing it to the bean. Regarding the Apache Camel docu there is 5 bean method options (ref, method, beanType, scope and trim) to use.
How can I set the trim option to prevent removing the space character from the delimiter in the bean?

**DSL code**

```
static final String DELIMITER = ", ";

    .setProperty("regex", simple(REGEX)) 
    .setProperty("delimiter", simple(DELIMITER)) 
    .bean("regexAgrsMessageBean", "searchRegexInText") //how can I set the trim option here
```

**Bean**

```
@Component
public class RegexAgrsMessageBean {

    public static String searchRegexInText(@Body String text, @ExchangeProperty("regex") String regex,
            @ExchangeProperty("delimiter") String delimiter) {
        
        LOGGER.info("delimiter: '"+delimiter+"'");

        return "";
    }
}
```

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/languages/bean-language.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn9sY.png)

**camel.version: 3.15.0**

Comment: Are you sure that your delimiter is actually taken from the set property? Your class method tries to inject a header value which you don't provide in your example. Furthermore, try to avoid `static` "class" methods for bean invocations. [Camel's documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/bean-binding.html#_parameter_binding_using_method_option) includes samples on how to pass arguments to invoked bean methods also

Comment: @RomanVottner:  Thanks for the hint, I have actually tried the same with the header but I forgot to change it back again. I changed it in the code to ExchangeProperty.

Comment: If you still have problems with Camel trimming the provided delimiter you can always pass the int-based code-point instead of the string representation to the method and later on convert the code-point back to the string based representation based on the char-set of the body

Comment: @RomanVottner: Yes I still have the problem. I did not unterstand you point with  int-based code-point. Could you plaese provide an example? What about the trim option in the bean method regaring to the Apache Camel docu? https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/languages/bean-language.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```java
// 2nd param to constant() is trim
.setProperty("delimiter", constant(DELIMITER, false))
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I am wondering how should it work with the trim option of the bean method as documented here: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/languages/bean-language.html

Comment: I think the problem was that it was getting trimmed immediately, before the bean invocation.